# How to take required bits from a string in php?

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have a data frame converted to binary string.I need to extract particular bits from that string.Could anyone please tell me how can I do that?

I have this binary string and have splitted this string into array. I am able to access each single bit but not able to take chunk from it.

$str="11110000111100000001**101010101010**0010**101110111011**";

```
print_r(str_split($str));
```

I want that particular bits in bold from the string  and print that.

```
$var=101010101010;
echo ($var);
$var2=101110111011;
echo ($var2);
```

This is typeof what is needed but not able to understand how do I take it from the string.

Comment: So explode it at the space character, and simply access the elements with index 0 and 3 in the resulting array …? (If that’s what you actually want, because right now from your description, that is anything but clear.)

Comment: What determines which part you want?  Matching values? Position? The alignment of the stars?  Can’t give much of a meaningful answer without context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the position of the chunk you want and the length of the chunk you want you can use [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

```
$str="111100001111000000011010101010100010101110111011";

$startPos = 20;
$length = 12;

$output=substr($str, $startPos, $length);
echo $output; // 101010101010
```

Comment: Thank you  for your help. This solved my problem and  gives me exact what was needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `preg_match` for it. This will find all the specific chunks you're looking for and list them in an array.

```
$str="11110000111100000001 101010101010 0010 101110111011";
preg_match_all("/(101010101010)|(101110111011)/", $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]); //0th index gives you all the matches
```

This will give you a result like this:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(12) "101010101010" [1]=> string(12) "101110111011" }
```

You can then loop through the array and print each value if you want:

```
foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
    echo $match.PHP_EOL;    
}
```